# Migrating between majior versions of Netty

Tags: netty

I am successfully using Netty 3.x. I would like to migrate to the current stable release version of Netty. Is 4.0.28 the recommended current stable released version of Netty? Is there any documentation on migrating between major versions of Netty?

Answer (score 0):

The recommend major version at the moment is 4.0.27.Final. For the migration the best is:

http://netty.io/wiki/new-and-noteworthy-in-4.0.html